# Improper format reading the serial port in C#

Tags: c#, arduino

I am reading data from an Arduino board using C#.

In C#, I have the following:

```
// Write a string
port.Write("x");

Thread.Sleep(50);
SerialPortRead();
```

... and in `SerialPortRead()` I have:

```
private static void SerialPortRead()
{
    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
}

private static void port_DataReceived(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
}
```

and, the output would look something like:

```
329327

32

7

327


3



26



327




3





26





32


7
```

What did I do wrong? The output should be a around 326-329, where this value is coming from a compass which is hooked up to one of the pins that I am reading from Arduino.

Note that:

In Arduino, I have a Serial read method that watch for the input character x and return the value of the compass.

Comment: I'd recommend to use [ReadByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte.aspx) to debug the issue - you may be reading mix of binary/text...

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you are reading faster that the compass is writing. So that way your program believes that it is receiving two direction, while if it has delayed reading a little bit it would have received only one.

This hypothesis is supported by that if you group the read data into numbers of three, we get directions in the range you expect.

Try adding a delay before reading after sending the trigger character, or even better - add a control character to signal that the compass has written the entire direction and then read until you receive that char.

Edit: I now noticed that you already have a sleep - so the option remaining would be a separation/termination char.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Without more info on your setup, i.e. code from both sides, the answer is no.